# Drupal login doesn't work after migration

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I recently moved a drupal 7 instance from the main domain to a sub-domain, i.e. from `example.com` to `old.example.com`. I added `$base_url` to settings.php so it fixed styles & scripts. However, login doesn't work: I'm getting "Sorry, unrecognized username or password." error - but I'm sure that both un&pw are 100% correct.

I know that this question was asked for a hundred times, but all solutions that I googled didn't helped me:

1. setting cookie_domain in settings.php
2. disabling clean_urls
3. run update.php

and etc. 
Maybe there is something that I'm missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like you're just having an issue with Drupal. What does this have to do with WordPress?

Comment: right, sorry just picked wrong tag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using the same `settings.php` file, and so a different password hash salt.

Open the old site `settings.php`, and copy the value inside `$drupal_hash_salt` to your new `settings.php` file.

Comment: no I'm using the same settings file, hash salt wasn't changed.